# authenticate to a Rest web api using Azure

Tags: azure-web-app-service, adal.js

I have a web api rest web service.  The web api, is already configure to authenticate to azure.

Now I want to call the rest web service from a web page using angular. the question is how can I get an access token so I can send it ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

have you seen this sample? [Call an Azure AD protected Web API in an AngularJS Single Page App](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi)

In this sample, there's a Single Page Application using AngularJS, that also calls another backend Web API.

I hope this helps.